# Advise on Java GUI Component Layout strategy

Tags: java, user-interface

I am hoping someone can offer a strategy for the following Java GUI:

I am implementing a Scrabble-like algorithm and I would like to write a GUI where a user can compete with the algorithm.  My experience with GUIs is limited and I am trying to avoid a big learning curve if someone can suggest a useful subset of components upon which I can focus.

I would like to display two playing areas side by side.  Each playing area contains a board and a tile holder.  Tiles from the holder can be dragged and dropped onto the board.

Obviously, the basic component is the tile, which is just a square displaying a letter.  The tile holder and the board are both tile containers (grids of different sizes).  The playing areas each hold the two tile containers and allow dragging and dropping from one container to the other.

The layout of the two playing areas is: the board on top, the tile holder on the bottom, and some neutral space between them.

The layout for the window is just to display the two playing areas side by side.

Perhaps naively, it seems to me I don't need much.  But finding the right pieces is proving to be quite a task.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Make your models observable. Follow MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top level JPanel with a GridLayout, 1 row, 2 columns, will create for you a panel with two evenly split areas. After that you can add another JPanel for each side (just sequentially add them), and these two JPanels can have a BorderLayout. For these two BorderLayout JPanels, you can add to each the following:

- A JPanel with a FlowLayout of ImageIcons that hold a pictures of a scrabble tile, and this JPanel will be added to the south position on the BorderLayout JPanel.
- Another JPanel with a custom class you'll make called ScrabbleBoard extends JComponent. Here you can extend paintComponent and draw the board how you wish, probably making use of obtaining the width and height so you can draw a board that scales to how much space you have available for the component. This custom JComponent will be added to the center position of the BorderLayout JPanel.

A component added to the center position of a BorderLayout tries to be greedy and takes up as much room as possible, while components on the sides do not, so it's often a good choice for UI's that require a small navigation or menu control area, and a larger area to view what is considered the main graphics.